# What happens with the beta-binomial distribution, when n approaches infinity?

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, beta-binomial-distribution, proof

Short question: What happens to the beta-binomial distribution, when n increases to infinity? Is there a count distribution arising like it's for the classical binomial distribution?

Answer (score 2):

Consider the [urn model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta-binomial_distribution#Beta-binomial_as_an_urn_model) for the beta-binomial:

> ... imagine an urn containing α red balls and β black balls, where random draws are made. If a red ball is observed, then two red balls are returned to the urn. Likewise, if a black ball is drawn, it is replaced and another black ball is added to the urn. If this is repeated n times, then the probability of observing k red balls follows a beta-binomial distribution with parameters n,α and β.

When both $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are very large, the additional balls introduced do not appreciably change the chances of red or black.  **This is just a binomial experiment** (with fixed probabilities $\alpha / (\alpha + \beta)$ of red and $\beta/ (\alpha + \beta)$ of black).

Comment: I think $\alpha, \beta$ are fixed and he's sending $n\rightarrow\infty$

Comment: @JMS If that's the case, you recover the underlying Beta distribution if you divide by $n$.

Comment: Right; without additional scaling the beta-binomial won't converge to a proper probability distribution as $n\rightarrow\infty$ if $\alpha, \beta$ are fixed (I think). From his phrasing ("count distribution") I think the OP may be looking for the analogue of a binomial approaching a Poisson as $n\rightarrow \infty$ if $p\rightarrow 0$ and $np$ is constant. Probably there is a similar result if you send $\alpha/(\alpha+\beta)$ to zero at a proper rate or something, but I don't know it.